# jquery - make original DIV's text vanish

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning jQuery, here's my very simple jquery page:
http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1452/

As you can see it works pretty well, but the problem is it looks a bit crappy when the original text `<div id="slender-trigger">nnnn</div>` still shows through.

How do I make the "Slender-trigger" div's text vanish when the other div (slender) is being shown? (It has to come back when the other div vanishes again of course)

As a sidenote, any idea how I can stop the "flickering" of the "slender-trigger" div when the mouse is over the "slender" div box?

Comment: The obvious way: `$("#slender-trigger").text("");` Note that you'd likely want to reinsert it on hover out

Comment: But then you are deleting the text, once the other div vanishes the original text should come back... in my simple example there is just one box but there can be dozens of these boxes

Comment: You don't even need javascript for this http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/RBJ9R/1453/ :)

Comment: Haha! Thats pretty awesome (and shows how little I know of CSS!) Thanks! But I would still also like to know how this is done using jQuery so I can learn from it (voted your comment up!)

Comment: @Ryan Just in case pure CSS solution without flickering. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/RBJ9R/1455/

Comment: Awesome dude, thanks again (voted again!)

Comment: Perhaps write it as an answer as well for future people searching for something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the text to the element with jQuery data.

For example:

```
$("#slender-trigger").data("text", $("#slender-trigger").text());
```

Then it's just as simple as:

```
$("#slender-trigger").hover(function() { 
 $("#slender").toggle();
 if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
   $("#slender-trigger").text("")
 } else {
   $("#slender-trigger").text($("#slender-trigger").data("text"));
 }
});
```

[jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1)

[jQuery Data](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

**Edit** Multiple Boxes Scenario.

Lets say all your boxes you want to hide are class (slender-trigger) notice I am not using ids now because that only fits for one box.

Save all the text data of the boxes:

```
$(".slender-trigger").each(function(index, element){ //Iterate the boxes
   $(this).data("text", $(this).text());
});
```

Now lets attach the hover element:

```
$(".slender-trigger").hover(function(e) {
  $(this).next().toggle();
 if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
   $(this).text("")
 } else {
   $(this).text($(this).data("text"));
 }
});
```

**Edit**: Made it only into one function, so you'll enjoy all three hoverIn, hoverOut and hoverInOut in one function.

Comment: Can't test this right now, will this work with multiple boxes?

Comment: No, but the idea is the same. You'll have to use an iterator for your boxes, save the data. Iterate all boxes, attach the hover event. I'll put an example.

Comment: Just tried it on Fiddle, not working: http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1461/  I thought this could be solved in jQuery using a simple function call and $this...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Quick question, looking at the fiddle you posted above this comment, is there some way to take out the flickering when the mouse moves over the 'slender' div?

Comment: It flicks because when you hover over it, #slender gets on top of #slender-trigger, which triggers hover out of #slender-trigger, because it's blocking it, i.e. you are not hovering over it anymore, you are hovering over #slender. Put #slender inside #slender-trigger and you'll be hovering over both of them. CSS might need to change a little bit. For multiple elements you'll have to use `$(this).children().toggle();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slender-trigger").hover( function() { $("#slender").toggle();
                 if ($("#slender").is(":visible")) {
                    $("#slender-trigger").text("");
                 }
                 else {
                    $("#slender-trigger").text("nnnn");
                 }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! the problem with this approach is there can be dozens of these boxes and I don't want to have dozens of these jquery if()s. Instead of deleting the text and bringing it back, I was thinking of just hiding the text then bringing it back